# Imperfect pixel when using CSS skew

Tags: html, css, skew

[image] **<-- see image with imperfect pixel here.**

[image]

When using skew in CSS I get a imperfect pixel where the skewed grey border meets the grey bottom border. Looks like some sort of outline or box-shadow. But using `outline:0;box-shadow:0;` does not effect it. Does anyone know how I can solve this? Cheers and thanks in advance! ✌️

**Edit, relevant code:** https://jsfiddle.net/acnodrfe/

Comment: also post your `HTML` so we can take a better look of your problem

Comment: Have updated the post with a jsfiddle, the problem is very hard to see there tho.

Comment: Does the 'line' come and go depending on zoom level?

Comment: It stays like that when use zoom, but that can be correct. Because it's made to stay like that when zooming by using the `vw` unit, you can check that on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue background color of that element was causing this. The grey border did get a little bit of blue from the bg with it. Changing the background with: `background: linear-gradient(270deg, #0b19ba 0%, #0b19ba 99%, #cccccc 100%);` solved the problem. Because it gives the edge close to that border a grey value.

PS: This was only possible because I have the light blue element on top of it so you don't see the gradient. Be aware of that if someone might need and find this later on in time.